# Matlab program to convert files in folder isn't iterating

Tags: matlab

There seems to be an issue contained within 'save' that prevents this program from properly iterating over each file and creating the output.

The goal is to take a folder full of .wav files and convert them all to .dat or ascii .txt...

Any ideas?

```
dir_in = '/waves'; % set directory

filelist = dir(fullfile(dir_in, '*.wav')); % get file list
for i = 1 : length(filelist) % iterate over files in dir
    filename = filelist(i).name;
    disp(['Processing ' num2str(i) '/' num2str(length(filelist)) ': ' filename])
    [data, fs] = audioread(fullfile(dir_in,filename)); % Do your stuff for every file
    save ['sampleOutput_' filename(1:end-4) '.txt'] data -ASCII % add filename to output filename, but without '.wav'
end
```

Comment: Just as an example, if I use this line to save "save 'file%d.txt' data -ASCII" ... it'll iterate through the files in the directory as expected but just continually overwrite the file

Comment: With dynamic filenames you can't use spaces to separate inputs, try `save(['sampleOutput_' filename(1:end-4) '.txt'],'data','-ASCII')`.

Comment: @David You nailed it! Thank you... submit as an answer so i can mark it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "command form" of Matlab functions, using spaces and no brackets (i.e. `save filename.mat var1 var2`) is quite limited. If you are using dynamic filenames, or using variables as filenames, you need to use the regular function-calling syntax: `save(['sampleOutput_' filename(1:end-4) '.txt'],'data','-ASCII')`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the above answer is correct about the limitations of the "command form" of matlab functions. In this case you should probably avoid it. Secondly, the save function in matlab is for saving out .mat files that would contain variables and structures. From my experience, it's not useful for saving out text files containing data. I would probably replace that line with something like:

writematrix(data, strrep(filename, '.wav', '.txt'));

If you want it to be tab delimited (it's comma delimited by default), you could try:

writematrix(data, ['sampleOutput_' strrep(filename, '.wav', '.txt')],'Delimiter','tab');

Update:
Apparently you can use the "save" function in that way! I had no idea. Thanks!

Comment: :) That's awesome!